# Adaptive images affecting subfolder websites

Tags: php, .htaccess, responsive-design

So this is my folder structure - [image: folder structure]

In the root folder, I also have a .htaccess and an adaptive-images.php file. The htaccess tells the 'base' level website to use adaptive images to serve its images at a lower res for lower res screens.

However, a site within an 'another website' folder is not showing images now. This is the site in question http://rrrepo.co/ - and if you try and open one of the images in a new tab you see this - http://rrrepo.co/img/A.png

It's saying that it cannot find the adaptive-images file in it's parent folder.

I don't want adaptive images on this website. I don't know why it says it can't find the adaptive images file, when the base level site is using it just fine.

Is the base level htaccess affecting all the other sites in folders?

Anyone know how to fix?

Thanks

EDIT:

the .htacess in the root

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
# enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "modification plus 3 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType image/pjpeg "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "modification plus 3 week"
ExpiresByType text/html "modification"
ExpiresByType text/css "modification"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "modification plus 3 week"
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#  Options +FollowSymlinks
  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  RewriteEngine On

  # Adaptive-Images -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new line, as follows:
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ignore-this-directory
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !and-ignore-this-directory-too

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets

  # don't apply the AI behaviour to images inside AI's cache folder:
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ai-cache

  # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
  # to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions

  RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php

  # END Adaptive-Images -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Add your .htaccess in the question [edit]

Comment: Croises - I have added it

Comment: The problem is in your `adaptive-images.php`you rewrite all images to this page

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid, but what do you mean by 'rewriting all the images to this page'? And how would I fix this? Thanks

Comment: If you can add the php code where you load the image. Certainly a relative link problem.

Comment: Yes, your rule `RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php`  rewrite (redirect without browser link change) all jpeg, jpg, gif, png images to root `adaptive-images.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want adaptive images at all, you can just delete (or add # before rules).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ai-cache
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php
```

If it's just for one domain, you can add line before RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.exemple\.com$ [NC]
# your actual RewriteRule:
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php
```

Comment: Thanks man. I actually just changed the folder structure so that the root website is in it's own subfolder and that fixed it.